# Accessing .NSF files without paying for domino subscription

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Do we need to pay for domino server subscription, when all we need is a way to access old .nsf files offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't subscribe to anything. You can download Lotus Domino Designer from IBM web site for free and access to your NSF files offline. You have to have the correct ID file, though.

Comment: You should check the licence agreement carefully if you plan to use the free version of Domino Designer. It's not intended to be used in the way you want to, so I wouldn't be surprised to find some clause that would put you outside the licence. For example you cannot connect it to a server without a Enterprise Client Access licence.

Answer (score 2):

When you say subscribe, that implies an ongoing payment, e.g. paying yearly and getting support and updates.

You don't have to "Subscribe" to the Notes Client or Domino server to continue using them after your maintenance period is up.

Comment: The exact words I was hoping to hear

Answer (score 1):

You can access Notes Database files from a local filesystem/network share using the Notes Client, just make a copy/replica to 'Local'. Don't forget to uncheck local encryption if you want other user id's to be able to access the file.

Comment: Which means to say that it is possible for me to simply subscribe to Notes, without paying for the more expensive Domino server? And still be able to access the old archives?